# Meu logo em bootstrap está demasiado grande e os restantes menus têm um grande espaço vazio

Tags: html, css

[image: Alguém me consegue ajudar a concertar isto?]

Alguém consegue ajudar me a concertar isto? Já utilizei o CSS, mas mesmo assim não consigo fazer com que os menus fiquem "colados" à imagem.

---

O meu HTML é o seguinte, e embaixo estará também o css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Comsidere adicionar seu código à pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Precisamos do seu código para ter certeza. Acredito que nos seus links você está chamando a classe

> `nav navbar-nav navbar-right`

Basta retirar a classe navbar-right e o conteúdo virá para o lado da logo de imediato.

Comment: Nao, por acaso a minha nav bar está  assim (class="nav navbar-nav")

Comment: Então realmente precisamos ver seu código. Pode ser que sua logo esteja empurrando o conteúdo também, mas duvido.
Posta o HTML e qualquer CSS adicional.

Comment: Aparece que o logo tem a dimesão de todo aquele espaço, isto é, o css está a reconhecer como se a parte "vazia" que está entre o logo e os menus dropdown faça parte do logo, e que o mesmo esteja a empurrar os menus.

Comment: Sem seu código não da pra ter ideia do que está acontecendo.